# ItemsControl data binding... binding to the current item isn't working

Tags: wcf, binding, itemscontrol

I have the following ItemsControl page...

```
<Page x:Class="Kiosk.View.ItemListView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:Kiosk.Converter" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Margin="10"
      Title="ItemListView">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Width="130" Height="130" Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" 
                Command="BrowseBack" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventClassSummaries}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <Converter:OxiStringConverter x:Key="oxiStringConverter" />
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Height="1000" Width="900" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                            Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}"
                            Height="42"
                            Width="440"
                            FontSize="12pt"
                            Margin="4"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The `EventClassSummaries` is working correctly, as I am getting the right number of buttons in my wrap-panel, the data is sourced from a WCF service, and the individual items are as follows (from the service end)

```
[DataContract]
public class EventClassSummary
{
    [DataMember] public string Category;
    [DataMember] public char Displayed;
    [DataMember] public int Id;
    [DataMember] public string Name;
    [DataMember] public char Status;
}
```

The problem I have is the Buttons do not display the `Name` binding and I just get blanks.

Oddly this was working on Friday, but I've had to rebuild the service and add some additional methods (although I didn't touch the ones relevant to this!?)

Does anyone have ideas, I find it a bit strange that this used to work (I even demo'ed it to PM's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DataBinding to work with WPF, you need to change your fields to properties.

So change:

```
[DataMember] public string Name;
```

to:

```
public string _Name;
[DataMember]
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { _Name = value; }
}
```

**Side note**: Hope you don't mind me preaching, but it is not good practice to be referencing your data transfer classes in the presentation layer - you should think about separating your layers.

Comment: Don't worry, this isn't final code, I'm just prototyping, but aside from that can you explain why these public properties were working before?

Comment: It did, I wanted to get some idea as to why this was working before I added the get / set's.