# Has it ever been possible to bind to a field in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

Someone suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228621/itemscontrol-data-binding-binding-to-the-current-item-isnt-working/5229469#5229469) that they, at some point, were able to bind a value to a field in WPF.

I know that this is [not a supported scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields) (and personally I have only seen binding work with properties), but is it even technically possible?

Comment: Of course it works.  That's the whole point of data binding.  What seems to be your particular problem?

Comment: @Stephen: You can't data bind directly to a field in WPF.

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  I misread.  I mixed up "property" with "field".  Fields are not possible, I believe, which causes no end of dismay for programmers, especially before auto-implement properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Binding in WPF uses either a [PropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx) or the Dependency Property mechanism, which only works on Properties.

(Technical note here: A Dependency Property is technically sort of a field - it's defined as a field, then registered with the DP system, though, and treated more like a property, so I would still call it a property...  The field itself doesn't actually store the data in the case of a DP.)