# How to bind list of objects to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all I have read all of the smilier questions and tried their answers. Nothing seems to work for me.

I created a class named `student`. Then I have loaded a list of student from a database.

Now, I wish to show this list in a datagrid. All I get is an empty table.. :(

What seems to be the problem? (I tried datacontext instead of itemSource)

My C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<student> studentsList = new List<student>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Classes.studentManager stdManager = new Classes.studentManager();


            studentsList = stdManager.Select();

            this.dgStudents.DataContext = studentsList.ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML code is as follows

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="211" Name="dgStudents" Width="Auto" Margin="39,0,-33,-142" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="birthDate" Width="175" Binding="{BindingfirstName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

This is student object

```
  public class student
  {

    public int ID;
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string studentID;
    public string homePhone;
    public string cellPhone;
    public string parentsPhone;
    public string parentsName;
    public string adress;
    public bool isPicFormExists;
    public string medProblems;
    public bool isParentsConfExists;
    public List<Class> classesList;
    public DateTime birthDate;
    public List<payments> payments;
    public double accountBalance;


    public student() 
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TO-DO
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have properties or variables in student class?

Comment: What does this statement do "studentsList = stdManager.Select();"?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Andrey already solved it. As nit suggested I changed it to properties...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define public properties in your `student` class. You cannot bind to fields.

WPF supports binding to properties of an object, not fields.

See this question for more info: [Has it ever been possible to bind to a field in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387206/has-it-ever-been-possible-to-bind-to-a-field-in-wpf)